# How to detect a new RC vote started / passed for Apache open source applications programmatically?

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, open-source, apache-zeppelin

Our team has a use case where we want to test new version of Apache open source applications (map reduce related) as soon as they pass RC voting.

Right now all these RC voting happens in email threads and different applications could have different format of RC voting email format.
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/zeppelin-dev/201705.mbox/browser

Sample voting thread for Zeppelin 0.7.3:
https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/1cffa2241670b935837c422aac8ec1a7fb70a89481d69bc0b9249ec4@%3Cdev.zeppelin.apache.org%3E

Right now we can subscribe to Apache application mailing lists, and manually check to find an email saying RC voting passed.

However, finding RC voting emails take time since there a lot of emails not related to RC voting. We want to get notified about RC voting start date and its targeting voting end date.

One of teammate has tried to build a RC thread scraper that fetches RC voting info by regex, but since there is no uniformed format of RC voting threads it's hard to capture all threads for all applications with this tool.

We need to test new release asap, and ideally before it shows in GitHub release branch. We can test against tags with RC# for some applications, but different applications have different tag name conventions.

Currently we manually check RC voting for the following applications:
Hadoop, Hive, Spark, Hbase, Zeppelin

Any idea how to automate the process of checking RC voting emails?